# REDUX The way of creating another similar components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an button A with a value , when i click the button the value will be increased one,
It works now with Redux **what if i want to add another button B with the same function , but the value is individual .**

Should i just create another pair of ACTION and Reducer for the new button ?
or there is another way to enhance my existing code? Thank You

**//initialState**

```
var initialState = {
        age:0
        }
```

**// action creators**

```
function clickAdd() {
  return {
      type: 'CLICK_ADD'
  }
}
```

**// reducre**

```
function reducreForAge(state = initialState, action) {
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return 0
  }
  var age;
  switch(action.type) {
      case 'CLICK_ADD': {
          return {
              age: state.age + 1
              }

      }
      default :{
          return state
      }
  }
}
```

**//Component**

```
var ButtonGroup = React.createClass({

  render() {

      const { age } = this.props;     

        return (
          <ButtonToolbar style={{width: 17+ 'em'}} >
          <Button id="buttonA" onClick={this.props.clickAdd} >{age}</Button>
          <Button id="buttonB" onClick={this.props.clickAdd} >{age}</Button>
          </ButtonToolbar> 
        );
      }
});
```

**//connect**

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return Redux.bindActionCreators({
        clickAdd:clickAdd
  }, dispatch);
 }


function mapStateToProps(state) {  
    return {  
        age: state.reducreForAge.age
    }  
}  

const NewButtonGroup = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use payload in action to specify increment item.

Lets consider

```
var initialState = {
        age:0
        anotherItem:0
}
```

action will be

```
function clickAdd(itemToIncre) {
  return {
      type: 'CLICK_ADD',
      payload:itemToIncre  // either age or anotherItem which ever you want to increment
  }
}
```

reducer

```
function reducreForAge(state = initialState, action) {
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return 0
  }
  var age;
  switch(action.type) {
      case 'CLICK_ADD': {
          return {...state,[action.payload]:state[action.payload]+1}
      }
      default :{
          return state
      }
  }
}
```

Now time came to decide which button will increment which item like
button1 which increment `age` and another button will increment `anotheritem` then action call must be like `this.props.clickAdd('age')` and `this.props.clickAdd('anotheritem')` respectively

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    clickAdd: (itemToIncre) => dispatch(clickAdd(itemToIncre))
})
```

Comment: it should be: `[action.payload]:state[action.payload]+1` :)

Comment: My mistake. @MayankShukla Thank you :)

Comment: thx guys....how about the mapStateToProps , do i need to add a new state named  anotheritem: state.reducreForAge.anotheritem ?? and add       const { anotheritem } = this.props;     in the Component ?

Comment: Yes as you need to specify them while connecting component.

Comment: sorry  is it right way to set the  mapDispatchToProps  with  clickAdd(itemToIncre):clickAdd(itemToIncre)